# Magento 1.9 JS problem

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery, menu

I have a search autocomplete to search a products. If it works other modules are not working (banner slider, brand logo slider, product slider, sticky menu and sticky header).

**autocomplete** has 2 js files:

- js/ves_autocomplete/noconflict.js
- js/ves_autocomplete/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js

**Banner slider** has 4 js files

- js/jquery.js
- js/base.js
- js/lightslider.js
- js/homePage.js

**Menu** has 2 js files:

- js/menu/jquery-1.js
- js/menu/menu-jquery2.js

**Sticky Header**, **Menu** have

- jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
- jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
- js/stickyMojo.js

When I just hide all the other js fileson my site, search autocomplete works; but i need to keep this design. Does anybody have an idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Each of the modules registers several jQuery-files, and in the end you have several different versions on you page. This results in Javascript errors, you can see them when you open Firebug, or your browser's developer tools.

There are also some other errors on the site, and I am not sure if they come from the jQuery-files; looks like some of the plugins are using the noConflict()-mode, and others don't.

You should make sure that you only have one jQuery-version included in you design.

Comment: can you suggest one jquery version to all ?

Comment: No, sorry. I would always aim to use the highest stable version available; however, some of your modules might not be compatible with the newest version. The challenge now is to find a version that all of the modules work with. I personally have had very few problems with 1.9 in most of the cases I had this problem.

Comment: oh god i need to find the problem  where it is.

Comment: If you'd have a problem finding a one version that all modules works on you can give a try the jquery-migrate version.